# Invoke same action for all urls in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a single page app in the new ASP 5. How can I tell it to always server Home/Index no matter what (unless the request has wwwroot in the path)?

More specifically, I would like something like this:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "Home/Index/");
            });
```

where first it searches the static files and then it if none are found, it just serves up Home/Index

Comment: You need to research routing. :)

Comment: "no matter what" is kind of a broad statement.  Do you also mean for 404 errors?

Comment: @David Yeah, that works. If ever a file does not exist that matches that route, I just want to server up Home/Index.

Comment: @David edited OP to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a catch-all route?

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
     routes.MapRoute(
          name: "default",
          template: "{*url}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```