# How to always default route for every request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 and I am hosting a AngularJS SPA.

I am using UI Router, which works fine, but when I refresh the page on a route, for example `/customer/5` I get a blank page.  I expect this is because I haven't got a route / controller associated with that route.

Ideally in this case I would want MVC to serve up "index.html" (my default page) that contains all my AngularJS code and then let UI router show the correct page.

How do I do this?  Here is a subset of my current `Configure` function in `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseMvc();
app.UseDefaultFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Comment: You can configure routing in the `UseMvc` call: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/25eb50120eceb62fd24ab5404210428fcdf0c400/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Builder/MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L66

Comment: You have issue in your angular routing I think

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926027/invoke-same-action-for-all-urls-in-asp-net-core-mvc/35927964#35927964

Comment: @tmg this is exactly what I am looking for, but, how do I make it go to a specific file rather than a route? I literally don't have an MVC controller at the minute or any routing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a custom Middleware before MVC in pipeline to handle all non-ajax and non-static file requests.

```
 app.UseStaticFiles();

 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
 {
      if (!Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) && context.Request.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != "XMLHttpRequest")
      {
           await context.Response.WriteAsync(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("index.html"));
      }

      await next();
 });

 app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine, however if I remove `UseMVC()` it works but if I remove `services.AddMvc();` I get an error, why is this? I use WebAPI controllers, does the `AddMvc` call allow this to work, and the `UseMVC` call is only for traditional razor rendering?

Comment: All are same controllers in asp.net-core. They will not work. I will update the answer later today.

Comment: This does work and I got my routes working but one thing I am actually worried about if what if the route is actually supposed to be 404 (no resource)? Do I need to code that in into my angular routes?

Comment: If you will request a static file (route with extension) you will get 404 if the file does  not exist.

Comment: Anyone know if this would risk causing any noticeable overhead?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue when using Asp.net core 1.1 web api & SPA (React-Redux created from CLI) separately.
I'm hosting SPA as static files inside wwwroot folder

The code below works for me.

```
 app.UseDefaultFiles();
 app.UseStaticFiles();

 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
 {
    if (!context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/api"))
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/");
        //context.Response.Redirect($"/#{context.Request.Path.Value}");
        return;
    }
    await next();
 });
 app.UseMvc();
```